# IronSource Mediation: AdColony adapter called Fyber now and is not found

Tags: adcolony, ironsource, fyber, digital-turbine

Adding AdColony (refered to Digital Turbine in IronSource documentation) as mediation network shows **Fyber** as Adapter to add to build.gradle.

```
// Add Fyber Network (Adapter only)
implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:fyberadapter:4.3.29'
implementation "com.fyber:marketplace-sdk:8.2.5"
```

Adding this adapter still makes IronSource own integration validator to fail for AdColony.

```
2024-01-10 10:10:00.101 IntegrationHelper com.package  I  Verifying Integration:
2024-01-10 10:10:00.112 IntegrationHelper com.package  I  *** Permissions ***
2024-01-10 10:10:00.121 IntegrationHelper com.package  I  android.permission.INTERNET - VERIFIED
2024-01-10 10:10:00.122 IntegrationHelper com.package  I  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE - VERIFIED
2024-01-10 10:10:00.123 IntegrationHelper com.package  I  --------------- AdColony --------------
2024-01-10 10:10:00.129 IntegrationHelper com.package  E  Adapter - MISSING
2024-01-10 10:10:00.130 IntegrationHelper com.package  E  >>>> AdColony - NOT VERIFIED
```

Answer (score 0):

The integration validator of IronSource is not adapted for AdColony now using Fyber adapter and SDK.

Adding Fyber for AdColony (Digital Turbine) is right

```
// Add Fyber Network (Adapter only)
implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:fyberadapter:4.3.29'
implementation "com.fyber:marketplace-sdk:8.2.5"
```

But be aware. At the moment this still fails due to mismatches from IronSource side. IronSource SDK still looks for com.ironsource.adapters.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter.

There is still work needed from IronSource to match AdColony to new Fyber adapter and IronSource SDK.